# How to have different styles for common componnent instance in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have a component called the amount component which is a shared library and I want to use that component in multiple places and I want to give that component different styles from where i use it. How to achieve it in angular ?

PS: amount component, needs styles for background, h2, button.

Comment: define different classes and use [ngClass] to conditionally define it. You can also use [ngStyle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give custom styles to your `account-component` by adding an Input Attribute by using the @Input() Decorator & pass the *styles or class name* to that component depending upon where it is opened from.
Then you can use ngClass or ngStyle to apply those styles to your component.

For example in your account-component:

```js
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() customClass: string;
}
```

Account Component HMTL

```html
<div [ngClass]="customClass"> <h1>Account Component</h1> </div>
```

Account Component CSS

```css
customClassRed:{
  color: red;
}

customClassBlue:{
  color: blue;
}
```

and in your components where you are opening account-component from just pass the class name (if you use the class name, then you need that class with styles in your components.css as I did above) or the styles depending upon your preferences

Another Component

```html
<account-component [customClass]="customClassBlue"> </account-component>
```

Comment: HassanMoin thanks for the answer, Is there a way to get it to work without @Input

Comment: It depends on how you are structuring your application. For example if your account-component is on a different route then you can use the route to conditionally add or remove the CSS classes